# How do we use 'pretty much" in this sentence?

Tags: adverbs, parts-of-speech

> You would succeed in pretty much everything.

I wonder what is the part of speech of 'pretty much', which part does it modify? 'succeed' or 'everything'?

In my point of view, it modifies 'everything', however, after checking the meaning of 'pretty much' and it seems it is an adverb. So I'm quite confused about the use of pretty much here in the sentence.

Comment: It's exactly the same as ***almost*** (both syntactically and semantically). So you could say *He pretty much gave up* as an "adverbial" usage, but in your *specific* example it's modifying the noun ***everything***, so obviously that's an "adjectival" usage. Don't forget that words like "adverb" and "adjective" apply to ***the use of a specific word in a specific context***, not to just the word in isolation.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonicaThank you for your explanation.